# How can I make my php files more secure, android?

Tags: php, android, database

I made a couple of php files for the login/registration part of my android project and I wanted to know if there was a way to make them more secure. Code for files posted below.

config.php:

```
<?php
    define('hostname', 'localhost');
    define('username', 'username');
    define('password', 'password');
    define('db_name', 'database');
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php

    require_once 'config.php';

    class DB_Connection {

        private $connect;
        function __construct() {
            $this->connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, db_name) or die("db connection error");
        }

        public function get_connection() {
            return $this->connect;
        }

    }

?>
```

register.php:

```
<?php

    require_once 'connection.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    class User {

        private $db;
        private $connection;

        function __construct() {
            $this->db = new DB_Connection();
            $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
        }

        public function registration($email,$username,$password) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO users(email,username,password) VALUES ('$email','$username','$password')";
            $is_inserted = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
            if ($is_inserted == 1) {
                $json['success'] = 'account for '.$username.' was created';
            } else {
                $json['error'] = 'email or username is already taken';
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }

    }

    $user = new User();
    if (isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (!empty($email) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $encrypted_password = md5($password);
            $user -> registration($email,$username,$encrypted_password);
        } else {
            $json['error'] = 'please fill in all fields';
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
    }

?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php

    require_once 'connection.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    class User {

        private $db;
        private $connection;

        function __construct() {
            $this->db = new DB_Connection();
            $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
        }

        public function login($username,$password) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $json['success'] = 'welcome '.$username;
            } else {
                $json['error'] = 'incorrect username or password';
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }

    }

    $user = new User();
    if (isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $encrypted_password = md5($password);
            $user -> login($username, $encrypted_password);
        } else {
            $json['error'] = 'you must fill out all fields';
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance for all and any help!

Comment: You can post this question on Code Review to get better answers.

Comment: @Skynet didn't know about that. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: at least multiple place can be changed for db performance/security issue..imo, but in one spot where md5 is used, md5 is very easy to crack with today technology, you might want to look into `password_hash` from 5.5.0, or  `crypt(BLOWFISH)` if you use php >= 5.3.7

Comment: @Andrew how would I change md5 to crypt(BLOWFISH) or password_hash? could you help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php